# How to change Product Website programmatically?

Tags: magento-2.1

[image]

My code can add new product to website, but I can't seem to find way to define product website value, e.g default to 'base'.

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create();
$product->setSku($column['requestcode']);
$product->setAttributeSetId(10)
->setWebsiteIds(array(0))
->setStoreId(0);
$product->setPrice($column['price'])
->setDescription($column['description'])
->setName($column['name'])
->setTypeId('virtual')
->setStatus(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset or set product website use below code . may be

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create();
$product->setSku($column['requestcode']);
$product->setAttributeSetId(10)
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) # Website id, 1 is default            
        ->setStoreId(0);
$product->setPrice($column['price'])
        ->setDescription($column['description'])
        ->setName($column['name'])
        ->setTypeId('virtual')
        ->setStatus(1);
$product->save();
```

Also you can use below code to ser website

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
```

Comment: so to figure what attribute correspond to what i downloaded an export of catalog, within that there is a column called 'website_id' and the one i want is called 'product_websites', that why I got confused was trying to use same value set for the former, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed the `->save()` action. So just add `$product->save()` in the end of your code, it should be OK.

Comment: I do have the save() action, I have other code before it is called, it was kinda long so I didn't copy whole thing, but thanks for the comment